# httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream() is ignoring id="0"

Tags: c#, json

I have a XML having nodes like

```
<leaderboardStat ID="0" statName="xxxx">
<leaderboardStat ID="1" statName="yyyy">
<leaderboardStat ID="2" statName="uuuu">
<leaderboardStat ID="3" statName="iiiii">
```

I am using

```
httpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            httpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxxx", "xxxxxx");
            httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
            httpWebRequest.Accept = "text/json";
            httpWebRequest.Timeout = 420000;
            httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false;
            httpWebRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 420000;

using (HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default))
            {
                content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                streamReader.Close();
            }
        }
```

issue is it is not reading the id="0" other than that it reads everything. Any ideas what is going wrong.

Comment: Your json not seems to be a json.... why `<` and not `{` ? IT not read only the attribute ID or the entire row?

Comment: Yup please read as XML

Comment: And in the variable 'content' you only find `<leaderboardStat ID="1" statName="yyyy">
<leaderboardStat ID="2" statName="uuuu">                                            
<leaderboardStat ID="3" statName="iiiii">`, without the first row right?

Comment: Yes it even reads statName="xxxx"

Comment: The first tag is interrupted or is complete? What i mean you see that:

`<leaderboardStat statName="xxxx">
<leaderboardStat ID="1" statName="yyyy">
<leaderboardStat ID="2" statName="uuuu">
<leaderboardStat ID="3" statName="iiiii">`
Or an interrupted tag? Like that: `statName="xxxx">
<leaderboardStat ID="1" statName="yyyy">
<leaderboardStat ID="2" statName="uuuu">
<leaderboardStat ID="3" statName="iiiii">`

Comment: The main issue is
 httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
 httpWebRequest.Accept = "text/json";
Not sure why it is missing the id ="0"